# bounds for the sum of the alternating p-series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to prove that for every $\alpha > 0$ the sum of the series $$1-{1\over2^\alpha}+{1\over3^\alpha}-+\cdots$$ lies between $1/2$ and $1$. The second part is easy for one can write the partial sums of the above as $1-({1\over2^\alpha}-{1\over3^\alpha})-\cdots$. Also the first part is easy for $\alpha \ge 1$ since again each partial sum is greater than $1-{1\over2^\alpha}$ which is greater than $1/2$. However as $\alpha$ tends to $0$ we clearly need more terms to reach $1/2$. I need a hint for the case $0<\alpha<1$.